# Java 8 way of adding in custom elements to a collection?

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-8

Is there a java 8 way of doing the following?

```
for(int i;i<=100;i++){
    Person person=new Person();
    person.setId(i);
    person.setName("name"+i);
    list.add(person)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add elements to already existing list, or can we create and return new one? Does constructor like `new Person(id, name)` exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
    .forEach(i -> {
       Person person=new Person();
       person.setId(i);
       person.setName("name"+i);
       list.add(person);
     });
```

**EDIT:**

As commented below, accessing an existing list inside the lambda expression parameter of the stream operation goes against functional programming. It's better to do:

```
List<Person> persons = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> {
       Person person=new Person();
       person.setId(i);
       person.setName("name" + i);
       return person;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html.

Comment: This doesn't compile. And using `forEach` is probably not a good idea: it is discouraged to use it in such cases. For example, if you run it in parallel, you would be surprised at the result.

Comment: yes it doesn't compile with foreach, I tried editing the answer but could not . Any specific drawbacks of using forEach ?

Comment: Apologies as I don't have access to a compiler right now... @Tunaki is right. You should avoid stateful lambdas [especially when doing parallel stuff](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#stateful_lambda_expressions). This simple approach may only be accepted if the stream operation is serial.

Comment: This works, but using a stream in this way offers no benefit over the for loop.  Streams are cool, but that doesn't mean we should replace all loops with streams.

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain a list of persons by mapping each `int` from 0 to 100 into a `Person`.

```
List<Person> persons = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).mapToObj(i -> {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(i);
    person.setName("name" + i);
    return person;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, you can append that `persons` list into an existing one for example.

[`IntStream.rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) return a `IntStream` of primitive `int`. Each is mapped to the object `Person` with [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) and collected into a list with [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

It would be cleaner if you had a constructor of `Person` taking the id and the name. With such a constructor, you could write:

```
List<Person> persons = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100)
                                .mapToObj(i -> new Person(i, "name" + i))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```